# How to add Loading image on top of another image on click [Jquery]

Tags: jquery, image, get, loading

Guys I've implemented a banner gallery as described in following:

```
<div class="Container">
                <div class="Gallery">
                    <div class="GaleryLeftPanel">
                        <img id="img1" src="http://test-audioplanet.lumos.in.green.mysitehosted.com/Content/Public/images/1.png" style="z-index: 100" width="141"
                            height="140" alt="image 1" /></div>
                    <div class="GalleryMiddlePanel">
                        <img id="img2" src="http://test-audioplanet.lumos.in.green.mysitehosted.com/Content/Public/images/2.png" style="z-index: 99" width="141"
                            height="140" alt="image 2" /></div>
                    <div class="GaleryRightPanel">
                        <img id="img3" src="http://test-audioplanet.lumos.in.green.mysitehosted.com/Content/Public/images/3.png" style="z-index: 98" width="140"
                            height="140" alt="image 3" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>


$('img#img1').click(function () {
        var currentScr = $(this).attr('src');
        var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');
        var third = $('img#img3').attr('src');

        $('img#img3').attr('src', (second.indexOf("L") >= 0) ? second.replace('1L', '1').replace('2L', '2').replace('3L', '3') : second);
        $('img#img2').attr('src', currentScr.replace('1', '1L').replace('2', '2L').replace('3', '3L'));
        $('img#img1').attr('src', third);
    });

    $('img#img3').click(function () {
        var third = $(this).attr('src');
        var first = $('img#img1').attr('src');
        var second = $('img#img2').attr('src');

        $('img#img2').attr('src', third.replace('1', '1L').replace('2', '2L').replace('3', '3L'));
        $('img#img3').attr('src', first);
        $('img#img1').attr('src', (second.indexOf("L") >= 0) ? second.replace('1L', '1').replace('2L', '2').replace('3L', '3') : second);
});
```

You can see the action in following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6HHkT/6/

What I need is, If I click on First or Third Image, I need to add a Loading Image on Top of Second image until it loads with new Image.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to add a loading layer to your middle image. Up to you to add a background image to this layer, I usually use a white color bkg with opacity 0.5 and a loading wheel.

Then, register an event to catch the new image loaded event. I added this event to the first image for the demo.

```
$('img#img2').addClass('loading');

//Append image load callback            
$('img#img1').on('load',function() {
    $('img#img2').removeClass('loading');
    //alert ("The image has loaded!");        
});
```

Fiddle not completly addapted : http://jsfiddle.net/6HHkT/12/

As all the images are already loaded in the browser cache, you will not view the loading layer in action. Uncomment the alert() function to verify that the callback has been called.